# How to set write permission to folder in magento 2 in windows?

Tags: magento2, permissions

I want set write permission to folder `pub/static` in magento 2 in windows localhost. can anyone help me how to set write permission to folder usig CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give write permission by running below command in your CLI.

```
takeown /F <folder name>
```

For Example:

```
 takeown /F C:\wamp\www\Magento\www\pub\static
```

Comment: After apply takeown /F magento2.3, still i am getting error like 'generated' directory permission is read-only. How can i give write permission in windows ?

Comment: this worked for me along with removing the generated folder, 
I used Magento 2.3.4 and PHP 7.2.29 and given the permission to Magento root folder
takeown /F C:\xampp\htdocs\magento223

Answer (score 4):

you can Use takeown command to give write permission to the file

> takeown /r /d y /f *

^ Recursively give permission to all files without prompting "are you sure".

Use following with `icacls` set the access control list

> icacls * /t  /grant Everyone:F

This will recursively grant Full access to user group "Everyone" to all files in the folder.