# php bin/magento s:s:d -f errors how to do that?

Tags: magento2.2.7

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
>     File "D:/xampp/htdocs/zenmeds/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/info.json" cannot be opened Warning!fopen(D:/xampp/htdocs/zenmeds/var/v
>     iew_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/info.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: please tell me how to solve that error?

Comment: give 777 permission to your `var/`, `pub/static` and `generated/` directories

Comment: remove contents of pub/static/frontend and try again.

Comment: i am using local xampp server

Answer (score 1):

Key to the answer is "Permission denied". I am unfortunately no windows expert. But seems like it is answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123557/80251).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem description:**

The error is saying that **var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/info.json** is not openable by Magento cause can be the wrong file permission.

**Solution:**
Make a practice( what I prefer ) to run Magento commands as sudo if you are in linux machine to avoid such errors
such as

> sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the var/view_preprocessed/ folder have full access permission.

Try from project root,

> chmod -R 777 /var/*

Comment: i am using local xampp server we dont need permissions right?

Comment: you need permissions, but you can't chmod them, ensure the user running xampp can access that directory, you could experiment with running xampp as admin or ensuring the file and all subfolders are writable and readable by the xampp user

Comment: Permission access is compulsory. If you are using windows, try by right-clicking on root folder -> properties.